# Add variable inside foreach

Tags: javascript, html

I intend to add the value of the `valor` variable. For that I'm using this code:

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "602", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "602",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
];

var results = data.reduce(function(results, org) {
  (results[org.Id] = results[org.Id] || []).push(org);
  return results;
}, {});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {

 var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(i => {
    linha += `totalizando`;
    var ValorPacote = 0;
    Object.keys(results[i]).forEach(b => {
   
      valor = results[i][b].valor;
      
      ValorPacote = parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2) + parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2);
      linha += `${ValorPacote}`;
    })
  })
  $('#minhaDiv1').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" >Teste</button>

   <section id="s1">
      <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv1">
        
         <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrint" style="text-align:right;">Print</button>

         <div id="printThis">
            <div class="row pagmfalta">
            
               
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>
   </section>
```

But the problem is that when I run the code it is not adding and without, repeating the value twice. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Nasser Aldosari sum the value of rows with the same id. For example with id 552 , the total value is 85. This is the expected result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that toFixed() would return a string
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

You might want to first do the addition through `(parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y)).toFixed(2)` as follows

I hope this answers the question ( as I am not sure what was the initial question )

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve then codes after this changes should be sufficient:

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "602", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "602",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
];

var results = data.reduce(function(results, org) {
  (results[org.Id] = results[org.Id] || []).push(org);
  return results;
}, {});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {

 var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(i => {
    linha += `totalizando<br />`;
    var ValorPacote = 0;
    Object.keys(results[i]).forEach(b => {
      //console.warn(results[i], b, results[i][b].valor);
      valor = parseFloat(results[i][b].valor);
      ValorPacote += valor;     
    })
    linha += parseFloat(ValorPacote).toFixed(2) + '<br />';
  })
  $('#minhaDiv1').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" >Teste</button>

   <section id="s1">
      <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv1">
        
         <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrint" style="text-align:right;">Print</button>

         <div id="printThis">
            <div class="row pagmfalta">
            
               
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>
   </section>
```

What I fixed:

1. `valor` is string so I ussed `parseFloat` to convert it to number
2. I changed calulation of ValorPacote - now it is simple `ValorPacore += valor`
3. I moved printing `valorPacote` to `linha` outside of loop

And basically it was that.

I think the most problem and confusion to you could be this string/number conversion.

Comment: *"I'm not sure"* and *"I think"* does not explain the changes you made in your solution. Please read [answer].

Comment: @Łukasz Piotr Łuczak It's not adding up, can you check?

Comment: I have fixed and updated